# Bad data performance issue in hive

Tags: hive

Currently I'am facing with bad data performance issue.
eg. data in hive table,
columns: country, state, customer_name

there is a typo error in column state.
(i.e) **TN** but typed **TM**

Kindly help me how to overcome this issue by clearing the bad data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to load data into Temp table and then LOAD main Table with cross validation : data state table like (select * from temp_tbl where State exists in (select 'd' from STATE_TBL where parent.state = state)

This way program will not fail and capture errors into other record or file.